# How to change jpg quality export?

Tags: php, jpeg

In the following code, that stores a jpg in db, I need to know how to first change the jpg to 40% quality and then save? i tried with [`imagejpg`](http://php.net/imagejpeg), but it saves null-files:

```
function exportGraphics($table_name)
{
    $odbc_query = "SELECT * FROM " . $table_name;
    mkdir("TI/" . $table_name);

    $data = odbc_exec($this->odbc_id, $odbc_query);
    odbc_longreadlen($data, 10485760); // 10MB = 10485760
    while (odbc_fetch_row($data)) {
        $row = odbc_fetch_array($data);
        if ($row['GRD_ID'] != "") {
            $file_name_jpg = "TI/" . $table_name . "/" . $row['GRD_ID'] . ".jpg";
            $file = fopen($file_name_jpg, "w");
            fputs($file, $row['GRD_GRAPHIC']);
            fclose($file);
            set_time_limit(3600);
            unset($row);
        }
    }
    print "Ýêñïîðò êàðòèíîê èç òàáëèöû " . $table_name . " çàâåðøåí!";
}
```

> Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: gd
>   warning: one parameter to a memory allocation multiplication is
>   negative or zero, failing operation gracefully in
>   X:\denwer\www\denwer\tecdoc3.php on line 103
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]:
>   Passed data is not in 'WBMP' format in
>   X:\denwer\www\denwer\tecdoc3.php on line 103
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]:
>   Couldn't create GD Image Stream out of Data in
>   X:\denwer\www\denwer\tecdoc3.php on line 103
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: gd
>   warning: one parameter to a memory allocation multiplication is
>   negative or zero, failing operation gracefully in
>   X:\denwer\www\denwer\tecdoc3.php on line 103

original code:

```
 function exportGraphics($table_name) {
 $odbc_query = "SELECT * FROM " . $table_name;
 mkdir("TI/" . $table_name);

 $data = odbc_exec($this->odbc_id, $odbc_query);
 odbc_longreadlen($data, 10485760); //10MB = 10485760
 while(odbc_fetch_row($data)) 
 { 
 $row = odbc_fetch_array($data);
 if($row['GRD_ID'] != "") {
 $file_name_jp2 = "TI/" . $table_name . "/" . $row['GRD_ID'] . ".jp2";
 $file = fopen ($file_name_jp2, "w");
 fputs($file, $row['GRD_GRAPHIC']);
 fclose($file);
 set_time_limit(0);
 unset($row);
 }
 }
 print "Ýêñïîðò êàðòèíîê èç òàáëèöû " . $table_name . " çàâåðøåí!";
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function exportGraphics($table_name) {
    $odbc_query = "SELECT * FROM " . $table_name;
    mkdir("TI/" . $table_name);

    $data = odbc_exec($this->odbc_id, $odbc_query);
    odbc_longreadlen($data, 10485760); //10MB = 10485760
    while(odbc_fetch_row($data))
    {
        $row = odbc_fetch_array($data);
        if($row['GRD_ID'] != "") {
            $file_name_jpg = "TI/" . $table_name . "/" . $row['GRD_ID'] . ".jpg";

            // create GD graphic from string, call imagejpeg to save new image
            $im = imagecreatefromstring($row['GRD_GRAPHIC']);
            imagejpeg($im, $file_name_jpg, 40);

            set_time_limit(3600);
            unset($row);
        }
    }
    print "Ýêñïîðò êàðòèíîê èç òàáëèöû " . $table_name . " çàâåðøåí!";
}
```

Or is that exactly what you tried?

If for some reason that doesn't work, you can try:

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($row['GRD_GRAPHIC']);
ob_start();
imagejpeg($im, null, 40);
$imgData = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$file = fopen ($file_name_jpg, "w+b");
fputs($file, $imgData);
fclose($file);
```

EDIT: *The reason GD isn't working is because it doesn't support JPEG-2000 file format*

Possible solution: Install `imagemagick` on the server and try code like this:

```
$file_name_jpg = "TI/" . $table_name . "/" . $row['GRD_ID'] . ".jp2";
$file_out_jpg  = str_replace('.jp2', '.jpg', $file_name_jpg);

file_put_contents($file_name_jpg, $row['GRD_GRAPHIC']);

// execute imagemagick convert to change to jpeg with quality 40
exec("/usr/bin/convert $file_name_jpg -quality 40 -format jpg $file_out_jpg");
unlink($file_name_jpg); // get rid of temp jp2 file
```

Comment: what's warnings mean (add to question)

Comment: I think this line `$im = imagecreatefromstring($row['GRD_GRAPHIC']);` is failing because PHP doesn't think `$row['GRD_GRAPHIC']` is valid image data.  Is that data encoded in any way (e.g. base64) and what image format is it supposed to be, JPG?

Comment: jp2 must be, i added original script

Comment: That is your problem, GD doesn't support JPEG-2000 (jp2) files, only JPEG.

Comment: how to solve this? or it is simpler to sen this all files to such soft as (acdsee) and convert there? but there about 10,000 images

Comment: @PavelBY Added a possible solution.

Comment: one more question. If i delete unlink($file_name_jpg); // get rid of temp jp2 file  i get export off all entries in db, but than i still have jp2 files remaining, but if i write this then it's export only one entrie

Comment: Maybe the exec of convert isn't working, you should have a lot of `.jpg` files if it worked since it should output the final file to a .jpg extension with the same name as the .jp2 file.

Comment: it gives two files: jp2 and jpg (if delete that string a lot of jp2 and jpg)

Comment: while($row = odbc_fetch_row($data))
 {       if i change in such way, it does'nt work, only one empty jp2 ?

Comment: how to check data is a valid image data?